# WinForms App: Saving User-Entered API Key to 'config.json

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I'm working on a WinForms app, and I need help saving a user entered API key. I have a TextBox which the user enters the key, and I want to store it in a 'config.json' file when they click the save button. Any ideas on how to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the format for the 'config.json' file:

```
{
  "apikey": "",
  "steam64id": ""
}
```

Comment: You can write to a file with `File.WriteAllTexy("config.json",jsonString);`. Is the real question how to generate the JSON string?

Comment: [Adding configuration to windows forms on .NET 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65669920/7444103) -- [How to force a .NET 6 Winforms App to use appsettings.json instead of Settings.settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74804624/7444103)

Comment: This kind of thing should use the Data Protection API (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853/how-to-store-passwords-in-winforms-application) You can still create json, but write it there instead of the bare file system.

Comment: Better (more recent) reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096480/can-an-api-key-be-securely-stored-retrieved-by-a-windows-desktop-app